# Unable to use Zombie JS with Behat

Tags: javascript, behat, mink

I am unable to run my tests using Zombie as a headless browser.
The error I get is

```
    [RuntimeException]                                             
    Install MinkZombieDriver in order to activate zombie session.
```

My "behat.yml" file is

```
    default:
        extensions:
            Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: https://saucelabs.com/
            default_session: zombie
            javascript_session: zombie
            zombie: ~
```

And "composer.json"

```
    {
        "require": {
        "behat/behat": "2.4.*@stable",
        "behat/mink": "1.4.*@stable",
        "behat/mink-extension": "*",
        "behat/mink-sahi-driver": "*",
        "behat/mink-extension": "*",
        "behat/mink-zombie-driver": "*"

    },

    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    }
    }
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is saying the zombie driver is not installed. Run:

```
composer require behat/mink-zombie-driver
```